# Position of elements in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have 7 images. I need to see 5 images in one row, and 2 more images in another row below in the center. I made 5 images in a row, but I can not position the other 2 images in the center below. Also, in `responsive` version I need 2 images under each other and 1 image in the center and they need to have border-radius:100%, but it does not work. What`s wrong with my code?
This is html:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .ring {
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm col-6">
      <div class="single-specials text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s" style="border-radius: 0;">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" style="border-radius: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-6">
      <div class="single-specials text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="border-radius: 0;">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" style="border-radius: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-6 hightechxl">
      <div class="single-specials text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s" style="border-radius: 0;">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" style="border-radius: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-6">
      <div class="single-specials text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.7s" style="border-radius: 0;">
        <img src="img/2.png" style="border-radius: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-6">
      <div class="single-specials text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s" style="border-radius: 0;">
        <img src="img/1.png" style="border-radius: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="single-specials text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1.1s" style="border-radius: 0;">
        <img src="img/2.png" style="border-radius: 100%; width: 150px; height: 150px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="single-specials text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1.3s" style="border-radius: 0;">
        <img src="img/1.png" style="border-radius: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap4, if there is another decision without bootstrap, please, show me how.

Answer (score 0):

I just make to demonstrate code for you at: https://codepen.io/tien-bui/pen/mamemO

So the basic ideas of Bootstrap is every row have 12 col, so if you want to display 5 item in 1 row you need to set the col prefix at 2. For example: target small screen col-sm-2, target large screen col-lg-2. And you need to target all the device to achieve the responsive, it will look like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-6"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex, set width to 18% for example - that little less than 20% , which can take 5 items and it will give you some space for margin.

Use media query for the second version and set flex-basis to 48%.

```css
.cont{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item{
  flex-basis: 18%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}


@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .item {
    flex-basis: 48%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```